# Why should Applicative inherit from Functor?

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

Indeed it does:

```
λ :i Applicative 
class Functor f => Applicative (f :: * -> *) where
```

At the same time:

```
fmap f x = pure f <*> x
```

— by the laws of `Applicative` we can define `fmap` from `pure` & `<*>`.

I don't get why I should tediously define `fmap` every time I want an `Applicative` if, really, `fmap` can be automatically set up in terms of `pure` and `<*>`.

I gather it would be necessary if `pure` or `<*>` were somehow dependent on the definition of `fmap` but I fail to see why they have to.

Comment: Do you want your applicative to work with `fmap`? There's no reason for it *not* to inherit `Functor`, because of the trivial implementation you've described.

Comment: Yeah, defining `fmap` is about the least tedious thing you can do with any type where it's at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are proposals to make it's easier https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/IntrinsicSuperclasses the "default instances" problem itself is very difficult.

One challenge is how to deal with common superclasses:

```
fmap f x = pure f <*> x                            -- using Applicative
fmap f x = runIdentity (traverse (Identity . f) x) -- using Traversable
fmap f x = x >>= (return . f)               -- using Monad
```

Which one to pick?

So the best we can do now is to provide `fmapDefault` (as `Data.Traversable`) does; or use `pure f <*> x`; or `fmapRep` from [`Data.Functor.Rep`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.3/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html) when applicable.

Comment: `fmap f x = x >>= (return . f)`

Answer (score 8):

While `fmap` can be derived from `pure` and `<*>`, it is generally not the most efficient approach. Compare:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
fmap f Nothing = Nothing
fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)
```

with the work done using Applicative tools:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
-- inlining pure and <*> in: fmap f x = pure f <*> x
fmap f x = case (Just f) of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just f' -> case x of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just x' -> Just (f' x')
```

Pointlessly wrapping something up in a constructor just to do a pattern-match against it.

So, clearly it is useful to be able to define `fmap` independently of the Applicative functions. That *could* be done by making a single typeclass with all three functions, using a default implementation for `fmap` that you could override. However, there are types that make good Functor instances but not good Applicative instances, so you may need to implement just one. Thus, two typeclasses.

And since there are no types with Applicative instances but without Functor instances, you should be able to treat an Applicative as though it were a Functor, if you like; hence the extension relationship between the two.

However, if you tire of implementing Functor, you can (in most cases) ask GHC to derive the only possible implementation of Functor for you, with

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
data Boring a = Boring a deriving Functor
```

Comment: In most of the cases where `data Boring a = Boring a deriving Functor`, a standalone `deriving instance Functor Boring` will still work. It's really rare to have a functor where GHC won't be able to derive the functor instance in some way, and even in those cases it will be peanuts do write it by hand, compared to the `Applicative` instance.

Comment: I would expect GHC, with `-O`, to simplify the nested case, cos `case (Just f) of ...` will always pick the `Just` branch. Indeed SPJ implies that it does in fact do this optimisation in this talk https://youtu.be/uR_VzYxvbxg?t=43m59s . Of course it won't necessarily be able to do that rewrite for all applicatives.